# PHP Code first saves the input, but when clicked on another button it doesn't save it anymore

Tags: php

I wrote a Rock Paper Scissors code that first gets the input of player 1, it supposed to save it and then asks for the input of player 2, saves it and outputs the inputs of both the players.
But right now it only outputs the input of player 2, but if you enter the first input it still saves it, but after entering the second one is just doesn't save it anymore. Could someone please help me fix this?

```
<?php
if (!isset($keuze1)) {
    echo "
    <form method='GET'>
    <input type='submit' name='knop' value='Begin met spelen'></button>
    </form>
";
}

$knop = '';

if (isset($_GET['knop'])) {
    echo "
    <h2>Speler 1</h2>
    <form method='GET'>
    <select name='speler1'>
    <option value='steen'>Steen</option>
    <option value='papier'>Papier</option>
    <option value='schaar'>Schaar</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' name='keuze1' value='kiezen'>
    </form>;
    ";
}

$keuze1 = '';
$keuze2 = '';

if (isset($_GET['keuze1'])) {
    $keuze1 = $_GET['speler1'];
    echo "
    <h2>Speler 2</h2>
    <form method='GET'>
    <select name='speler2'>
    <option value='steen'>Steen</option>
    <option value='papier'>Papier</option>
    <option value='schaar'>Schaar</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' name='keuze2' value='kiezen'>
    </form>
    ";
} 

if (isset($_GET['keuze2'])) {
    $keuze2 = $_GET['speler2'];
    echo "
    Speler 1 koos $keuze1 en Speler 2 koos $keuze2
    ";
}

echo $keuze1;
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you consider "saving" here? Because I don't see you doing anything that would deserve that term _anywhere_ here.

Comment: The first choice is $_GET['speler1'], so I give the variable keuze1 to the first selected option

Comment: Looks to me like you are probably not aware yet, that each request is independent from the previous one? If you want to "save" values across requests - then you either need to make sure they get send again, with whatever causes the next request (like. put them into a hidden field in that new form your are submitting) - or you would have to store them into the _session_.

Comment: in your code, there is no persistence. When the first player submits his choice, $_GET['speler1'] will be set and $keuze1 will have a value. When the second user submits, $_GET['speler2'] will be set but $keuze1 won't have a value anymore because the page has been reloaded

Comment: Side note: PHP can be used a templating engine. To print a block of static HTML you can just close PHP tags (`?>`), dump the raw HTML and reopen PHP tags (`<?php`) if you need to add further PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you submit a form, the script starts over, and nothing is "saved" from one iteration to the next. So when you click the `<input type='submit' name='keuze2' value='kiezen'>` button, everything is reset and the only variables you have are the ones that are submitted in the form.

So if you want to bring `$keuze1` along, the easy way to do that is to pass it into a hidden form field, like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['keuze1'])) {
    echo "
    <h2>Speler 2</h2>
    <form method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='speler1' value=" . htmlspecialchars($_GET['speler1']) . " />
    <select name='speler2'>
    <option value='steen'>Steen</option>
    <option value='papier'>Papier</option>
    <option value='schaar'>Schaar</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' name='keuze2' value='kiezen'>
    </form>
    ";
}
```

... and then, get `$keuze1` from `$_GET['speler1']` in your final `if` block, before outputting it.